# How to have TestNG parameters in a separate suite file?

Tags: testng

I am trying to remove testng parameters from my suite files, as they are needed in multiple suites. For example, I have 2 test-suites, `upgrades.xml` and `features.xml`. I created a 3rd file, `parameters.xml`
The actual suite files I run look like this:

```
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="parameters.xml" />
    <suite-file path="features.xml" />
</suite-files>
```

The tests in `features.xml` are run, but they are all skipped because of configuration errors. If I paste my parameters directly in the file, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can set two suites parallel at the same time making one access to data in another.
Please have a try on this.

main.xml

```
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="features.xml" />
</suite-files>
```

features.xml

```
...
<parameter name="config" value="parameters.xml"/>
...
```

But you should make sure the parameters.xml is parsable in your application.